# Создание производного перечисления с ключами исходного в TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

### Задача

Создать перечисление или аналогичный тип `DerivedEnum`, ключи которого полностью совпадают с перечислением `SampleEnum`, при этом:

1. Внесение изменений в ключи `SampleEnum` (добавление новых, удаление или переименовывание уже существующих) должно сделать `DerivedEnum` невалидным. Иными словами, TypeScript должен сказать в виде ошибки: "Изменил `SampleEnum` - давай теперь `DerivedEnum` тоже меняй".
2. `SampleEnum` должна быть `enum`.

В принципе `SampleEnum` может иметь произвольный набор ключей, но поскольку для примера что-то нужно, то пусть это будет

```
enum SampleEnum {
  alpha: "FOO",
  bravo: "BAR"
}
```

### Отчёт о самостоятельном сборе информации

Начнём с того, что тупое ручное копирование типа

```
enum SampleEnum {
  alpha: "FOO",
  bravo: "BAR"
}

enum DerivedEnum {
  alpha: "BAZ",
  bravo: "HOGE"
}
```

решением не является, поскольку внесение изменений в `SampleEnum` не повлечёт за собой ошибки `TypeScript` по причине невалидности `DerivedEnum`. По сути, `DerivedEnum` полностью автономна по отношению к `SampleEnum` как и к любым переменным.

[`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) - это не то, что нужно, поскольку `keyof` даёт нам типы *значений*, а в этой задаче мы наследуем именно *ключи*, а не значения.

Наконец, я пытался задать [аналогичный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62887161/refer-the-keys-of-one-enum-to-keys-or-values-of-another-enum) на англоязычном StackOveflow. [Предложенное решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62906418/4818123) предполагает отказ от `enum`, а что бы про `enum` плохого не говорили, полноценной замены этой сущности пока нет. Другое дело, что получить `enum` на основе другой `enum` скорее всего, невозможно, потому `DerivedEnum` может быть и не `enum`, однако в рамках этой задачи `SampleEnum` является `enum` как данность.

Comment: _keyof даёт нам типы значений_ - вообще он дает именно список ключей.

Comment: @Grundy, совершенно согласен, что я чего-то не понимаю, но если `keyof` нам даёт список ключей (что впрочем очевидно из названия), то почему решение `{ [keyof SampleEnum ]: string }` невалидно? (как впрочем и `type DerivedEnum = Record<keyof SampleEnum, string>;`).

Comment: потому что `SampleEnum` - это `enum`, а `enum` - это обычный объект. И применяя к нему `keyof` ты получаешь все возможные ключи которые могут быть у объектов.

Comment: @Grundy, понял! Благодарю Вас за объяснения.

Comment: Хотя не совсем точное пояснение. Если в енаме, как у тебя в пример задаются строковые значения, `keyof` возвращает все ключи для `String`.  Если его убрать будут ключи для number. То есть в данном случае проблема именно в том, что используется `enum`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как-то вот так, если я правильно понял вопрос.

```
enum SampleEnum {
  alpha = "FOO",
  bravo = "BAR"
}

type DerivedEnum = {
  [key in keyof typeof SampleEnum]: string
}

const derivedEnum: DerivedEnum = {
  alpha: '123',
  bravo: '321',
};
```

Внесение изменений в ключи SampleEnum (добавление новых, удаление или переименовывание уже существующих) сделает derivedEnum не валидным.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за решение!