# Утилитарный тип "унаследовать ключи перечисления" в TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Из ответа на вопрос ["Создание призводного перечисления с ключами исходного в TypeScript"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1340081/193415) я узнал, что то, о чём я спрашиваю в вопросе, возможно:

```
enum SampleEnum {
  alpha = "FOO",
  bravo = "BAR"
}

type DerivedEnum = {
  [key in keyof typeof SampleEnum]: string
}

const derivedEnum: DerivedEnum = {
  alpha: '123',
  bravo: '321',
};
```

[Ссылка на исходное решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1340134/193415)

Теперь было бы неплохо создать утилитарный тип, который берёт все эти `in keyof typeof` на себя, а пользователю лишь остаётся указать исходное перечисление и тип значения для нового объекта.

Приведённое ниже попытка решения нерабочая:

```
export type InheritEnumerationKeys<Enumeration extends { [key: string]: string | number; }, ValueType> = {
  [key in keyof Enumeration]: ValueType
};
```

Честно говоря, я не понимаю до конца, что значит `in keyof`, а потому буду благодарен за объяснения по этому поводу помимо решения.

Comment: Нифига не понятно. Если значения независимы, то никакой утилитарный метод вместо тебя новые значения не придумает, а проверка пита у тебя уже есть. Если значения должны совпадать, то используй обычный spread-оператор: `const derived = { ...SampleEnum }`. И ещё, это нормально (хотя не уверен, что у тебя такое же понимание нормальности результата) работает только со строковыми енумами.

Comment: @Qwertiy "никакой утилитарный метод вместо тебя новые значения не придумает" - этого и не требуется, потому что унаследовать нужно только ключи, но не значения. Смысл том, чтобы обязать производный тип иметь такие же ключи, что и исходного перечисления.

Comment: Так у тебя это уже в вопросе есть. Чем не устраивает?

Comment: @Qwertiy Необходимостью каждый раз писать вручную `key in keyof typeof`. Нужно, чтобы это делал утилитарный тип. Daniil Loban как раз такой и предложил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начну с конца `in keyof` это цикл по ключам т.е. их перебор таким образом они добавляются в определяемую структуру.

Что касается решения то если я правильно понял суть [вот оно](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=34&ssc=26&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAyghhADgG2AUXNA3gKClOZRACzigF4oAiAMQHk6qAaPKAIwCc4A3AewuoAhAIIAlKjgC%20OHKEiwEKdJgBMUXPkIkylWg2atOPfrpHiW%20AOYIIO6mgDiDmBOk4ALgE9EwKABFgDgBLbmAAEwxIAB5BOABnZUgmKAA1QjBgABVvYAA%20AQ0oAG0Aa2BPKCCQKDLPXgAzKFiEyIgAXQAuVPSsnKkZAGNeEDj3KDDAkPDWroDg0IjMKK8fBoUkVFbk0eCQS3zKQq1SLoByAEYVAGZTi3YuPjOrlXPTqQBuQeHR8cmF1pUsz%200yWK2Aa3gG0SEGSmDYgQO6lYxzgXUuVzuRkeUGe5w%20XxGYwm8xBkCuQJJi2iYIhik2qlhkHhHERRyIJyg6MxD14XVxd2sEFsXRU%20JwQxGvFQADpkLxLAAKYlTKkQACU4u%20UuAsvlSuBqpUGolcW1usVyv%20mCuaqAA).

```
enum SampleEnum {
  alpha = "FOO",
  bravo = "BAR"
}

enum AnotherSampleEnum {
  alpha = "FOO",
  bravo = "BAR",
  gamma = "EGGS"
}

type DerivedEnum<BaseEnum, ValueType> = {
  [key in keyof BaseEnum]: ValueType
}

const derivedEnum: DerivedEnum<typeof SampleEnum, string> = {
  alpha: '123',
  bravo: '321'
};

const secondDerivedEnum: DerivedEnum<typeof SampleEnum, number> = {
  alpha: 123,
  bravo: 321
};

const thirdDerivedEnum: DerivedEnum<typeof AnotherSampleEnum, number> = {
  alpha: 123,
  bravo: 321,
  gamma: 2
};
```

Способом `type DerivedEnum<BaseEnum, ValueType>` мы определяем какие аргументы попадут в наше определение типа, это [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), далее их используем, для того чтобы передать тип `enum` а не сам `enum` мы используем `typeof`

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Подскажите пожалуйста, я правильно Вас понял, что решение `DerivedEnum<SampleEnum, string>` (а не `DerivedEnum<typeof SampleEnum, string>`) невозможно?

Comment: @БоковГлеб да, потому что `SampleEnum` не является типом, если бы оно было объявлено как `type` то тогда не понадобился бы `typeof` - а так он нужен как своеобразный трюк преобразовать `перечисление` в `тип` - хорошо что это работает

Comment: Хорошо, я Вас понял! Зачёл Ваш замечательный ответ и поставил плюсик.