# Ошибка TS2464 - случай объекта с унаследованными ключами и строчными значениями

Tags: typescript

В вопросе [Создание производного перечисления с ключами исходного в TypeScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1340081/193415) я ошибочно предположил, что `keyof` возвращает именно значения, а не ключи. Мне тогда было сказано, что `keyof` возвращает именно ключи. Но в этом примере что-то опять не сходится.

```
type EntryPointsRecognitionSettings__FromFile__RawValid = {
  excludeAllSubdirectories?: boolean;
  excludeSubdirectoriesWithNames?: Array<string> | string;
  excludeSubdirectoriesWithPrefixes?: Array<string> | string;
  excludeFilesWithPrefixes?: Array<string> | string;
};

type PropertiesKeys = { [key in keyof EntryPointsRecognitionSettings__FromFile__RawValid]: string; };

function test(propertiesKeys: PropertiesKeys): void {
    console.log({
        [propertiesKeys.excludeAllSubdirectories]: "ALPHA"
    })
}
```

В типе `PropertiesKeys` я вроде как корректно скопировал ключи `EntryPointsRecognitionSettings__FromFile__RawValid`  и указал, что значениями могут быть только строки. Если это так, то `propertiesKeys.excludeAllSubdirectories`, где `propertiesKeys` имеет тип `PropertiesKeys`, должно быть строкой. Тем не менее, судя по ошибке `TypeScript`, это не так:

```
A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.(2464)
```

Прошу Вас объяснить, что именно я не понимаю.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsATiACgewJYIM4CUIDGaA5nBsBmnAMoTAVzHYD6zAYomgLZsYA2EVrgCGAdwBqwvhgAmUALxQA3gFgAUFCgQAHgT4BXGRACCfPtX0AjGRkSFgaRBgjYA-AC4oltGgHC4ANzqmjp6hhAW1rb2js7YAOrkABYAcsJcLh5QxoiIwiAAPNhIWMQAfFAAPlDFToxBGlq6BkaRNnYEDk4uicBJKHYAZhjamZ45eYW1pRXV0-XBTWFGvAIJyQMQw6Nu47n5RSWMszVHxA0Avg3qoJBQA2iQiBQuANIQINgKylAA2gDWHygWCggJAaEGsAQyHQWGAeEIJDIFCotHopRY7E4PH4gmYIgkUlkAF1PPNzlArup1IN9HBOpQ4FBgC5gAAKMCcJ4vbDvT6eB7cuJ87AASk8ADdMHJVI1NEQ4NhfBAAHR8Ehs2WabXa36cx4QZ7Cj7YFWhFomMxtaKdWIuUlQABExgAMigABLGR2LTQXUXqC7UtTqIA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в `?` рядом с именем свойства.

Знак вопроса показывает, что свойство может отсутствовать. Таким образом тип ключей не просто `string`, а `string | undefined`.

Из-за этого напрямую такой ключ использовать нельзя, так как для ключей можно использовать только *'string', 'number', 'symbol', или 'any'*

Если ты хочешь использовать все ключи, в `mapped type` нужно указать, что они становятся обязательными

```
type PropertiesKeys = { [key in keyof EntryPointsRecognitionSettings__FromFile__RawValid]-?: string; };
```

Теперь ошибки не будет.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsATiACgewJYIM4CUIDGaA5nBsBmnAMoTAVzHYD6zAYomgLZsYA2EVrgCGAdwBqwvhgAmUALxQA3gFgAUFCgQAHgT4BXGRACCfPtX0AjGRkSFgaRBgjYA-AC4oltGgHC4ANzqmjp6hhAW1rb2js7YAOrkABYAcsJcLh5QxoiIwiAAPNhIWMQAfFAAPlDFToxBGlq6BkaRNnYEDk4uicBJKHYAZhjamZ45eYW1pRXV0-XBTWFGvAIJyQMQw6Nu47n5RSWMszVHxA0Avg3qoJBQA2iQiBQuANIQINgKylAA2gDWHygWCggJAaEGsAQyHQWGAeEIJDIFCotHopRY7E4PH4gmYIgkUlkAF0ALRZebnKBXdTqQb6OCdShwKDAFzAAAUYE4Txe2Hen08D15cQF2AAlJ4AG6YOSqRqaIhwbC+CAAOj4JA58s0ut1v25jwgz1FH2watCLRMZja0U6sRcxM8ACJjAAZFAACWMzsWmgu4vUF1panUQA)

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Да, это я допустил глупую ошибку. Теперь, когда я понял в чём дело, даже другой вариант решения скажу: `type PropertiesKeys = { [key in keyof Required<EntryPointsRecognitionSettings__FromFile__RawValid>]: string; };`.

Comment: @БоковГлеб, если посмотришь как определяется [Required](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype): `type Required<T> = { [P in keyof T]-?: T[P]; }` :)

Comment: Не знал про аннотацию типа `-?` :) Спасибо, что научили.

Comment: `undefined` - не тип ключей. Там гораздо мутнее фича с переносом вопросика...

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, так проще показать что ключ может отсутствовать